# Corda states data design

Tags: kotlin, architecture, blockchain, corda

I want to decide a design scenario on data storing using corda states. I like to know the best way to connect stateA with stateB where stateB can be linked with 3 different types.

**Option 1:**

Say, I have an **InsuranceServiceState** having

```
insuranceType: String // values will be "InsuranceTypeA", "InsuranceTypeB"

insuranceTypeData: AbstractInsuranceTypes // eg: Inherited by InsuranceTypeAClass
```

And we have `InsuranceTypeA`, `InsuranceTypeB` child classes inherited from it. So that according to the user input in **InsuranceServiceState**, any of these subclasses can be inserted to insuranceTypeData field.

Finally once **`InsuranceAgreementState`** is created, it will be referring to the StaticPointer of InsuranceServiceState to identify the service used.

**Option 2:**

No `insuranceTypeData: AbstractInsuranceTypes` field inside InsuranceServiceState, instead, two new corda states for InsuranceTypeA, InsuranceTypeB where it has InsuranceServiceState linearId for linking.

Now those InsuranceTypeA or InsuranceTypeB values can be updated without being updating the InsuranceServiceState.

Though in order to know the type used at the time of creation of InsuranceAgreementState, we need to add a

```
StaticPointer<InsuranceTypeA>
```

inside InsuranceAgreementState.

Which one is the best way to do it? What criteria I should look at?